# Как динамически добавить html елемент в Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

пример проблемы

```
let td = document.getElementById(id);
td.innerHTML = '<i nz-icon nzType="caret-up" nzTheme="outline"></i>';
```

я так понимаю что перед этим html нужно скомпилировать, но как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем вам такой ужас?

Comment: мне при определених условиях нужно засунуть туда иконку, и это сделать только через ts, так как html изменять не могу

Comment: При каких условиях? Должен существовать обходной путь, в котором вам не надо компилировать html.

Comment: у меня есть страница со списком, для всех сущностей эта страница почти одинаковая, но некоторые моменты изменяются, и что бы не плодить одинаковый html код под каждую сущность, я хочу иметь возможность изменять не которые элементы через callback и в этом случае мне нужно добавить html элемент

Comment: Что бы не писать дублирующийся html код в вашем распоряжении есть компоненты или директивы. Приведите реальный пример html, общий и который должен меняться по условию.

Answer (score 0):

Что мешает сделать так?

html:

```
<div *ngIf="условие показа иконки">
    <i nz-icon nzType="caret-up" nzTheme="outline"></i>
</div>
```

или непосредственно:

```
<i *ngIf="..." nz-icon nzType="caret-up" nzTheme="outline"></i>
```

Comment: таких условий может быть много, а этот html код будет на многих станицах, и выходит  много лишних действий там где их не нужно

а вот js будет исполняться только тогда когдна нужно

Comment: @МаксимКоханський вам следует уточнить вопрос, показав пример проблемы